# Foreach Array incrementando outro array

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, foreach

to com uma duvida em realizar um foreach e incrementar um outro auxiliar para realizar um insert no banco, vejam só:

Quando realizo um envio do meu form via post tenho o seguinte array como resultado:

```
array (size=2)
  'quantidade' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '10' (length=2)
      1 => string '11' (length=2)
      2 => string '15' (length=0)
      3 => string '22' (length=0)
      4 => string '10' (length=0)
      5 => string '9' (length=0)
      6 => string '0' (length=0)
      7 => string '35' (length=0)
  'produto' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '11' (length=1)
      1 => string '18' (length=1)
      2 => string '19' (length=1)
      3 => string '21' (length=1)
      4 => string '22' (length=2)
      5 => string '25' (length=2)
      6 => string '29' (length=2)
      7 => string '22' (length=2)
```

Como estou usando o CodeIgniter pra pegar os dados do Form, to usando a seguinte estrutura:

```
foreach ($this->input->post() as $chave => $valor) {
  //o array aux aqui
}
```

Alguma ideia de como gerar este resultado, pegando o primeiro valor de cada elemento e inserindo em um array auxiliar:

Tipo assim:

```
$array_aux[0] = array('quantidade' => 10, 'produto' => 11)
...
$array_aux[7] = array('quantidade' => 35, 'produto' => 22)
```

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer um for normal e 'controlar' os dois indices por `$i` ?

Comment: Ola @rray, então to usando o codeigniter e pegando essas variaveis atraves do $this->input->post(), por isso pensei no foreach. Saberia me auxiliar a usar o for pra isso?

Comment: Esse array auxiliar vc vai mandar para o banco? qual a estrutura dele?

Comment: sim, vou enviar ao banco. A estrutura do BD é id, quantidade. Que no exemplo que passei o id é igual a chave produto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arrayForm = array();

foreach($array['quantidade'] as $key => $val){
    $arrayForm[] = array(
                   'quantidade' => $val, 
                   'produto'    => $array['produtos'][$key]
    ); 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayForm);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: perfeito sua logica @Gumball saiu exatamente como precisava, e ainda posso adicionar novas chaves. O esquema é usar a variavel $key pra pegar as posicoes das minhas chaves correto?

Comment: Exatamente, pega a mesma chave dos dois arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Provavelmente o que você quer é isso:

```
array_combine( array $keys , array $values );
```

No seu caso:

```
$array_aux = array_combine( $array['quantidade'], $array ['produto'] );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Z5dfZs)**

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php

Comment: Opa @Bacco valeu pela ajuda com apenas uma linha. No caso to usando o CodeIgniter, e recebo os dados atraves do $this->input->post(), por isso usei o foreach, saberia me auxiliar neste caso?

Comment: Se o $this->input->post() retornar array, só fazer $array = $this->input->post() antes da linha acima, e se retorna objeto, só trocar o $array['quantidade'] por ->quantidade no objeto, e o mesmo no produto. Poste um print_r do seu $this->input->post() no pastebin e o link aqui nos comentários pra eu ver. De qq jeito, dá pra usar a mesma lógica.

Comment: Ok meu caro, vou realizar o post la no pastebin, de qualquer forma ja coloquei na descricao da pergunta o que voce pediu. No mais valeu pela ajuda novamente

Comment: De qq forma, não precisa de loop. A linha acima resolve. Mas mande o link do pastebin aqui que eu vejo se adapto.

Comment: Mas não se esqueça, ponha um print_r mesmo, pq ai dá pra ver toda estrutura.

Comment: Então, analisando o print estamos no caminho correto, so nao consegui montar as chaves como no exemplo $array_aux[0] = array('quantidade' => 10, 'produto' => 11), visto que isto será inserido no banco. Vou dar uma olhada aqui atraves do que vc me mandou

Comment: @tkmattos `$array = $this->input->post();` `$array_aux = array_combine( $array['quantidade'], $array ['produto'] );`

Comment: SIm @Bacco entendi esta logica, to tentando é montar aqui a ideia de criar os arrays pra inserir no banco, visto que cada par de produto e quantidade será um insert no banco, por isso vou precisar colocar nome nas chaves

Comment: @tkmattos eu tou indo pelo que vc colocou na pergunta, fica dificil imaginar como vc tá fazendo a inserção. Conforme for, abra uma pergunta com o código da inserção propriamente dito.

Comment: Tranquilo meu caro, daqui ja ajudou muito, vou tentar modificar com base no que me mandou, e coloco a resposta da pergunta pra ajudar a todos tbm. Mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda de sempre!!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48473/discussion-between-tkmattos-and-bacco).

Answer (score 3):

Se vai montar um array e fazer um insert via querybuilder do CI, normalmente os nomes das chaves devem ser os nomes das colunas no banco de dados, nesse caso pode usar a função `array_map()` para combinar os valores.

A função anônima retorna um array que terá como valor o primeiro (e demais) item de  `$a1['quantidade']` e `$a2['produto']`.

```
$a1 = array('quantidade' => array(10,11,15,22,10,9,0,35));
$a2 =  array('produto' => array(11,18,19,21,22,25,29,22));

$r = array_map(function($q, $p){ return ['quantidade' => $q, 'produto' => $p] ;}, $a1['quantidade'], $a2['produto']); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($r);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 10
            [produto] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 11
            [produto] => 18
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 15
            [produto] => 19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 22
            [produto] => 21
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 10
            [produto] => 22
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 9
            [produto] => 25
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 0
            [produto] => 29
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 35
            [produto] => 22
        )

)
```